# How to improve refreshing Pivot Table speed

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have this code which refreshes pivot table data.

```
Dim wsPT as Worksheet
Dim pt as PivotTable

Set wsPT = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

With wsPT
    For Each pt in .PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
End With
```

It is working fine,  but kinda slow.
I have 10 PT in the WS.
How can I improve the speed of updating?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Alternatively, if you want a Non VBA solution then in `Data Ribbon`, Click `Refresh All` or press the shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: ok, i'll try which is faster. But that will also refresh all other PT in other WS. btw, non VBA is not an option. The code is part of a larger code that automatically sends mail. I want to improve speed so as not to rely on `Application.Wait`.

Comment: Try `Application.Screenupdating = False` before updating and then set it back to `True`

Comment: Yep, this is way faster than the `For Loop`. Even without the `Application.Screenpudating` set to `False`. But it does significantly improve if you disable and enable `Application.Screenupdating` during and after the events. Thanks.